# How to prevent autofs from stalling system when nfs share is not available

Tags: nfs, automount, autofs

This problem has been there in OpenSuSE 10.1-12.3 and (K)Ubuntu 10.04-14.04 and I'd like to get rid of it now:

We have a common software directory on an NFS share. Client-side autofs setup

```
# /etc/auto.master
/-   /etc/auto.direct --ghost --timeout 30
```

and

```
# /etc/auto.direct
/usr/mysoft   -fstype=nfs,defaults   myserver:/exports/usr/mysoft
```

**Problem:** Of course, the directory `/usr/mysoft/bin` is in the `$PATH`, and when `myserver` is unavailable, all clients stall. That is:

- Login (even on tty1 shell) takes minutes to bring up bash prompt (if ever)
- Hitting the Tab key for shell completions sends the terminal into deadlock
- No binary (even if installed locally) can be launched

Is there a way to overcome or at least moderate that effect?

Does the position of `/usr/mysoft/bin` in the `$PATH` matter?

Comment: I think the best way would be to remove to the  directory from PATH